# How can I automatically determine fonts used in an image or PDF?

Tags: font-identification, software-recommendation

How is it possible to determine the fonts used by text in PDF and TIFF files?

Comment: [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/117786/74576) was helpful to me.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For TIFFs or any other raster (pixel) image, Jin's answer covers it.

For PDFs (assuming it's a 'proper' PDF and not a raster image embedded in a PDF, as produced by scanning/fax software), font information is embedded in the file.

In Adobe Reader, Adobe Acrobat, and Foxit Reader 3 -- probably slightly different in other applications -- File menu > Properties > Fonts tab gives you a list of all fonts used in the document.

There are also third-party plugins for Acrobat, such as [Enfocus PitStop Pro](http://www.enfocus.com/product.php?id=855), which add the ability to find/replace/report on instances of a particular font throughout a document.

Comment: ... and if you can't find the font info, you could try to take a screenshot of the PDF and send the sshot to *What the Font*.

Comment: Xpdf comes with pdffonts, cf. [man page](http://man.he.net/man1/pdffonts), a command line tool with switches to restrict its font listing to those from a page range.

Comment: I've made this community wiki, intending that all resources are compiled into one list.

Answer (score 35):

Upload a sample of the text screenshot to: http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ the service is fairly accurate.

Comment: or when WhatTheFont it doesn't work well (It happen), I go to the forum http://www.typophile.com/forum to ask the experts of the sector about it.

Answer (score 22):

If you need help identifying a font sample, there are lots of resources.

Some are automated, you submit a sample screenshot or go through a series of questions that help narrow the possibilities:

- http://identifont.com
- http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/
- http://www.bowfinprintworks.com/SerifGuide/serifsearch.php
- http://typenav.fontshop.com/

Some software can help find a font that's close to what you want:

- http://www.stretchedout.com/products/fontmatch/fontmatch.php

Others are human-driven, where experts and enthusiasts may examine your submission:

- http://typophile.com/forum/29
- http://www.flickr.com/groups/fonts-in-use/

Finally, there are services and programs designed to simply help you choose an appropriate font for a given use:

- http://www.adobe.com/type/fontfinder/

Answer (score 18):

On a Mac or Linux, open your terminal and type:

```
strings /path/to/your.pdf | grep -i fontname
```

Comment: This is the best answer because no new software is required. It took around half minute to output the lines but it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

Just to add to the list a new software to identify fonts using an image or screen capture:
"Find my Font" - http://www.findmyfont.com (I'm the developer of this software).

The application runs on either Mac-OS or Windows and identifies the fonts of a given bitmap image **by searching for fonts both online (125.000+ free & commercial fonts) and on your computer** while you are given a list of exact and similar matches + a % match for each one, in just 3-5 secs. It can use all kinds of color images without extra pre-processing.

Answer (score 9):

In a PDF with actual text, you can copy a block of text into Word (or another rich editor) and look at the Font dropdown.

Comment: pdf text generally copies without styling in some operating systems and some pdf readers.

Comment: And I doubt this would ever work for fonts you don't have installed on your system.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Summary

#### 1.1. Requirements

If your requirements:

1. free software or service
2. font identification for Cyrillic symbols

#### 1.2. Recommendation

Use:

1. [**FontMatch**](http://www.stretchedout.com/) for semi-automatically determination on images
2. pdffonts, strings or [**Foxit Reader**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/FoxitReader) for automatically identification into PDF files

---

### 2. Disclaimer

This answer is relevant for August 2019. In the future data of this answer may be obsolete.

---

### 3. PDF

You [**can use**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955425#comment70694684_8955457) [**img2pdf**](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) for converting your images to PDF files (and PDF-XChange Editor [**for optional adding OCR layer**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/66632/23324)) and use this software.

#### 3.1. pdffonts

Poppler tool [**pdffonts**](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-pdffonts/). Windows users can install Poppler [**via Chocolatey**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/poppler).

```
D:\SashaDebugging\FontsIdentification>pdffonts KiraGoddess.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Arial                                CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes      7  0
Arial                                TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no       8  0
```

#### 3.2. strings

As [**Kyle Cranmer said**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29420/66040). Windows users also can use strings tool, installing the necessary software from Chocolatey:

- strings [**is a part**](http://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/toolchain-july2009.html) of [**Strawberry Perl**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/StrawberryPerl)
- grep [**is a part**](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/shellscripting/grep) of [**Cygwin**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Cygwin).

```
D:\SashaDebugging\FontsIdentification>strings KiraGoddess.pdf | grep -i fontname
/FontName /Arial
/FontName /Arial
```

#### 3.3. Foxit Reader

`File` → `Properties` → `Fonts` as described in [**community wiki answer**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/377/66040):

[image: Foxit Reader]

#### 3.4. Limits

For some PDF files fonts may be:

1. not determined
2. determined incorrectly

I recheck pdffonts/strings/Foxit Reader results, use FontMatch.

---

### 4. FontMatch

You can use [**pdftoppm**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/66632/23324) for converting your PDF files to images and use FontMatch.

#### 4.1. Usage

Make screenshot of any letters from image → `File` → `Open` → select your screenshot file → `Identify` → FontMatch suggest possible fonts:

[image: FontMatch]

Manually compare top fonts from `Matching Fonts` list with your font. For comparing another letters it would be nice apply programs as [**Font Runner**](https://codeandrun.com/john/font-runner-2/) — [**open source**](https://bitbucket.org/jfamiglietti/font-runner/src/master/) local fonts viewer:

[image: Font Runner]

#### 4.2. Limits

1. Solely local fonts supported
2. Software [**no longer maintained**](http://www.stretchedout.com/)

---

### 5. Not helped

I tested `КираИдеал.jpg` on not human-driven services and software from [**`font-identification` tag description**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info).

#### 5.1. Data

- [**КираИдеал.jpg**](https://app.box.com/s/xz8swhjhqqt6silk17oyyxeq47g02jv9) — JPEG file with text `Кира Идеал!`

[image: КираИдеал.jpg]

#### 5.2. Not supported Cyrillic symbols

1. [**WhatTheFont**](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) — WTF:

   [image: WhatTheFont]
2. [**WhatFontIs**](https://www.whatfontis.com):

   [image: WhatFontIs]
3. [**Matcherator**](https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator):

   [image: Matcherator]
4. [**Identifont**](http://www.identifont.com) — Latin-specific guide:

   [image: Identifont1]

   [image: Identifont2]
5. [**Bowfin Printworks**](http://www.bowfinprintworks.com/SerifGuide/serifsearch.php) — also, Latin-specific guide:

   [image: Bowfin Printworks]

#### 5.3. Paid

1. Adobe Photoshop [**Match Fonts**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/fonts.html#match_fonts) — [**pricing**](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/pricing-info.html).
2. [**FindMyFont**](https://www.findmyfont.com) — 30 days usage period for free version:

   [image: FindMyFont]