# What font is used in this web app's menu button?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I am software developer on a legacy web application project. We have a menu bar whose buttons are a combination of an icon and some descriptive text. I am currently adding a new feature, and it requires a new button. Here is a sample button that I'm using as a guide:

[image]

Can anyone help identify the font used in that graphic?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining fonts used](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/determining-fonts-used)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That looks exactly like the icon and font used in Microsoft Office in Windows XP. So **Tahoma, 8 pt**. From the File menu...

[image]