# Which hand-drawn/calligraphic style font is used in this restaurant logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I need some fontphiles!

[image]

Which font is being used for the restaurant name? Any ideas?
I'm sorry the image is so small, it's the best one I could fine.
Apologies if this is not the right SE to ask this on.

Thanks so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining fonts used](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/determining-fonts-used)

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto: Please see Jaips answer.

Comment: Image is now missing - and question is a bit meaningless without it. Can you add a URL?

Comment: The image is still there. And the URL will expire to the image soon as the domain will be migrated and the content will be completely redone. Though, for now, the image is at http://joyluckfoods.com/assets/images/autogen/a_logocut.jpg --However, I do believe you answered this question successfully, e100.

Comment: Odd, it vanished for me temporarily. Would be good to have a URL that won't expire, though

Comment: Well, it's alright. I already got my answer -- it is Adobe Galahad. And the image in the post shouldn't expire as I uploaded that from my computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Adobe Galahad](http://myfonts.us/td-NDSJB8), possibly stretched by a few %.

[image]

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the answers to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/374/79) and let us know how you get on.

Comment: Fantastic tool. Unfortunately, I don't believe it's powerful enough for an image of this size, as I did not hit any positives. But I really like this website!

Comment: There's more than one resource suggested in the answers to that question.

Answer (score 1):

looks like the dreaded Papyrus to me.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first guess as well, however there's a clear difference between the two fonts.

Comment: What's so bad about Papyrus? It's not *that* bad, is it? :)

Comment: @JFW: I like Papyrus, but it's gotten over-used by people who aren't designers. This menu would be actually be one of the legitimate uses for it.

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Comment: @Darth_Vader Even "visual people" like "us graphic designers" know what Papyrus looks like without a screenshot. It's a very standard, widely-known, widely-distributed, widely-used font, and doesn't need a visual any more than Chicago does.

Comment: I disagree..  many people have said and i even believe you've said before that this site is for beginners and a beginner isnt going to know what you're referencing font wise and if they are looking at the right font.  This initiative is to make better quality answers, clarify what fonts are suggested and to help educate.