# What is the name of this semi-slab serif font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Could anyone tell me what this font is on the following images?

It looks like Courier but it is not.

[image: Screenshot image]

[image: Screenshot image 2]

Comment: See http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/determining-fonts-used/763#763

Comment: Simply from the title of this question alone, I knew the answer to this was going to be "Museo".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Museo. http://www.josbuivenga.demon.nl/museo.html

For future reference, http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ is really useful for finding out what a font is called (though I admit I recognised this one)

Comment: Note: Museo is very trendy right now, to the point where *some* might say it's becoming a cliche (or even ["the new Comic Sans"](http://www.builtbybalance.com/2011/10/04/museo-the-new-comic-sans/)).

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Comment: It's in the question....