# How can I automatically determine multiple fonts used in a single image?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I am looking for a tool that I can give it an image filled with different fonts and it will give me their font type.

I know of this tool:

http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Thing with this application is that it demands each font to be uploaded separately. This for my sorrow is not feasible for me.

Comment: Linked: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/determining-fonts-used-font-identification. Can you edit your question headline to mention the differentiator that you're looking to identify multiple fonts per image?

Comment: Are you looking to create a specimen book of all the fonts installed on your system? If so, many of the font management apps offer that as a feature.

Comment: Why is uploading the fonts separately not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the services in JYelton's [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-can-i-automatically-determine-fonts-used-in-an-image-or-pdf/763#763). At the very least the human-solution would be able to help.