# What font is used in the Best Western Hotels logo?

Tags: fonts, logo, font-identification

I'm interested in making a joke t-shirt for a friend that changes the text on the "Best Western" logo. Does anyone know what font that is (pictured below), or what font most closely simulates it?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi & welcome, similar questions have been asked here quite a few times. Try the solutions in this question first http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-can-i-automatically-determine-fonts-used-in-an-image-or-pdf let me know if that answers your question so we can close this one

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that tool, will most definitely be using it in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's custom designed - the neat joins between B and W, and s and t didn't happen by accident - but looks to be based on [ITC Century Std Bold Condensed](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/itc-century/bold-condensed/).

[Mockup](http://myfonts.us/td-NS3qH1) of 'Best Western' text sample - you might need to click into one of the controls to get it to display correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this image didn't work very well with [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), I did a little adjusting to the image and passed it through again.

Unfortunately, I got no perfect matches, but here are some very similar fonts:

[Whitman Display Comp Black](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/whitman-display/comp-black/)

[image]

[Gomorrah](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/chank/blinc-pak/gomorrah/)

[image]

[Consort RR Bold Condensed](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/redrooster/consort-rr/bold-condensed/)

[image]

[Benton Mod Disp Comp Bold](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/benton-modern-display/comp-bold/)

[image]

To the untrained eye, and without any comparison, I don't think anyone could tell the difference.

Comment: Consort is the only one that's fairly similar, with bracketed slab 'Clarendon' serifs.