# What font is used in this "Reality" video games poster?

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone help me identify the font used for the **heading** of [the following poster](http://encefalus.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/loser-video-game.jpg)?

[image]

Comment: [I reject your reality and substitute my own.](http://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/?p=297)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Impact font to me judging by the long letters and somewhat condensed shapes. All they did was used a bevel or inside shadow effect and applied a warp or a text shape to the word. Check this link out and use show by its caps. http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/impact/%7CImpact

Here's my quick rendition -- you can tell those letters match distinctively.

[image]

Comment: Yup, it's Impact all right. It's possible that the deep crotch in the Y has been tidied up a bit.

Comment: yes, because there's nothing worse than untidy Impact crotches.

Comment: The distortion is likely an 'envelope' filter (Adobe Illustrator has them).

Comment: thank you. This is great. To clarify something, are those lines found inside the letters drawn or can they be created with a bevel?

Comment: Beveling would be the first thing I'd experiment with. Probably with a few tries you'll be able to get the same effect. I couldn't tell off-hand how to do that though as I haven't tried it yet. Good luck though!

Answer (score 5):

We get a lot of font identification questions, you should check out [this link](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-can-i-automatically-determine-fonts-used-in-an-image-or-pdf).

However, I ran the header through [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and some close matches were:

[Interstate Compressed UltraBlack](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/interstate/ultrablackcompressed/)

[image]

Though, the R doesn't have the curve on the bottom...

[Folio Bold Condensed](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/folio/bold-condensed/)

[image]

Though, the font isn't as heavy...

I hope this helps.

As for the "retro" effect, I would duplicate the font layer, and change it to black, and drag it down a little bit (creating this sharp shadow). Then, I would use the pen tool to create those lines you see on top of the letters. It also looks like all the letters have a stroke around them, so I would add a black stroke too.

This technique should be nearly identical in both photoshop and GIMP.

**EDIT**
Mike's post includes the correct font, which is Impact.

Comment: +1 for providing sources and inline effect notes, but -1 for just giving the not-very-close matches from an automated identification tool.

Comment: Hey, when I ran the scan, that's what I got e100 :P

Comment: Yes, but (1) the user could run it themselves with the same results, and I think should be encouraged to do so before asking the question here (2) WhatTheFont's results are very patchy, e.g they seem to rate general proportion and weight over shape of letterforms. Impact is a very common font; it comes with either Windows or Office and is pretty easy to spot (3) Another answer provides the 100% correct answer and is currently scored lower.

Comment: I up-voted Mike's answer. I agree that his is better. Though, to be fair I included in my answer how the retro effect could be achieved. But I agree, the impact font is easy to spot, and I should have figured that out, and that's my error. :]

Comment: thank you for the effort and help. I appreciate that. I was not aware that there are font identification tools--now I am.