# Can anyone help me identify this font (Jannat Ghar)?

Tags: font-identification

[image: Font name ?]

can any one help me identify this font > I can't find this on the web or maybe my searching skills are not that good

Comment: Did you try http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I automatically determine fonts used in an image or PDF?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-can-i-automatically-determine-fonts-used-in-an-image-or-pdf)

Answer (score 5):

The font you are looking for is **Revue Regular**

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tilde/revue/regular/glyphs.html

[image]

Comment: AZfonts appears to be a site destributing pirated and/or rip-off typefaces. I've changed the URL to go to the version at MyFonts.