# Can I identify a font family from an image using any Adobe program?

Tags: font-identification, software-recommendation, typefaces

I have an image of a logo and want to find out which font family is used using an Adobe program or any other program, is that possible?

Comment: See [How can I automatically determine fonts used in an image or PDF?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/374/52050) and the [font-identification tag wiki](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a newer update of Photoshop they added this function!

1. Open the file in Photoshop CC.
2. Drag a marquee around the font you want to identify.
3. Go to the top and select type > match font.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can do this within newer versions of Photoshop, as stated in the other answer, I would suggest that you use a site like [WhatTheFont!](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) instead.

I find the Photoshop Match Font to be pretty limited, whereas WhatTheFont is more powerful and has yielded better results (for me).

We also have a pretty comprehensive list of font-ID sources in the [font-identification](/questions/tagged/font-identification) tag wiki, [click here for more info](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info)

**My advice, if you use WhatTheFont:**

- Save just the text portion of the logo you want to identify as a PNG
- Black text on a white background is ideal

[image]

[More tips from WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/tips.html)