# Identify serif font, similar to Centaur

Tags: font-identification

From a book published in 2006:

WhatTheFont says Centaur or Venetian 301, but notice how the serifs on upper `T` are vertical and the two strokes on lower `p` intersect (I do not know of a font with of both these).

[image: How to See Yourself As You Really Are]

Comment: Have you tried the [online font identifiers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97398/how-to-identify-fonts-from-images-scans/97415#97415) yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [Requiem from Hoefler/Monotype](http://www.typography.com/fonts/requiem/overview/).

[image]

It has a more flamboyant default 'Y' they didn't use.