# Font identification(Does anyone know what this font is?)

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can anyone identify this font on the pic? or can at least give me a font that is close/similar to this one?[image: '']

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SX! Although your question has been answered, I’ll mention this question where you can learn how to find fonts yourself in the future: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-can-i-automatically-determine-fonts-used-in-an-image-or-pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Love Hewits](https://creativemarket.com/maulanacreative/1858198-Love-Hewits-Typeface) from creativemarket.com

[image: love hewits font]